# Create a 'User Account' interface like in Windows using Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, user-accounts

I am developing an aplication for which I have to create an 'User Account' control panel similar to that in Winodows OS, Where logged in user can manage other users, his own password, etc.

I request you to please check how the 'User Account' control panel in Windows looks like and works.

Now you have noticed that there are options which look similar to web-links(when you bring your pointer on them, arrow changes to hand symbol), when you click on them, a different form is loaded on the same frame. Ex: What happens when you click on 'Change your password'?

I am not getting how to do this and how can we provide options that look like hyperlinks and on-clicking them, change the form.

Comment: if it is a desktop app you should try looking into awt/swing or if an enterprise then you have multiple options using jsf/primefaces

Comment: It's a desktop app and I am using swing. But I am unable to find what components to use for the functionality mentioned above.

Comment: The control you are looking for may be called a link button.

Comment: *"I request you to please check how the 'User Account' control panel in Windows looks like.."* Please supply me with an image.. *"..and works."* ..and a PC loaded with Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows such hyperlinks are implemented with [SysLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) standard control introduced with Windows XP.

There's no Link control in Swing. However, you can use `JXHyperlink` from [SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx) library, it's under LGPL-2.1 license.

If this license is not acceptable, then you can even implement one yourself. Custom component would look like label but behave as a button.

---

To change "forms", you would switch a displayable panel when user clicks a command link. I mean you'll hide the currently visible panel and display the new panel which provides UI for the command user clicked. You can think of it as a tabbed dialog but tab bar is invisible and you switch the active tab programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Alexey! The idea of switching panels seems great! I'll try this and look into SwingX library and will come back.